# Error while installing - cannot find GCC and G++

Tags: python

I'm trying to install fbpy, a simple Python library that allows drawing on the framebuffer. While installing, I get a bunch of warnings and one error about the cross compiler. What am I missing here? I've checked GCC and G++ and they're both in /usr/bin. The error:

```
Warning: Extension name 'fblib' does not match fully qualified name 'fbpy.utils.fblib' of './fbpy/utils/fblib.pyx'
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'fblib' extension
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-9xgeTe/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c ./fbpy/utils/fblib.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/./fbpy/utils/fblib.o
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1788:0,
                 from /usr/include/python2.7/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
                 from /usr/include/python2.7/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from ./fbpy/utils/fblib.c:422:
/usr/include/python2.7/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
  ^~~~~~~
In file included from ./fbpy/utils/fblib.c:424:0:
./fbpy/utils/test.h:10:1: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
 };
 ^
In file included from ./fbpy/utils/fblib.c:425:0:
./fbpy/utils/audio.h:36:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 int mainz();
 ^~~
In file included from ./fbpy/utils/fblib.c:426:0:
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.h:9:1: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
 };
 ^
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.h:17:1: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
 };
 ^
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.h:28:1: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
 };
 ^
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.h:43:1: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
 };
 ^
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.h:57:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 extern int keepcurrent();
 ^~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.h:59:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 extern int cleartmpbuffer();
 ^~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.h:60:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 extern int clearscreen();
 ^~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.h:64:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 extern int kernel();
 ^~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.h:70:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 extern int snow();
 ^~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.h:95:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 extern int getHeight();
 ^~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.h:96:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 extern int getWidth();
 ^~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.h:97:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 extern int styledredraw();
 ^~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fblib.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_4fbpy_5utils_5fblib_78fbjackoff’:
./fbpy/utils/fblib.c:6176:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘kwit’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   kwit();
   ^~~~
./fbpy/utils/fblib.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_4fbpy_5utils_5fblib_80fbgetnframes’:
./fbpy/utils/fblib.c:6244:36: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getnframes’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyInt_From_int(getnframes()); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 381, __pyx_L1_error)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fblib.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_4fbpy_5utils_5fblib_82fbreadjack’:
./fbpy/utils/fblib.c:6376:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘readout’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   readout(((double *)__pyx_v_audioL->data), ((double *)__pyx_v_audioR->data));
   ^~~~~~~
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-9xgeTe/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c ./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/./fbpy/utils/fbutils.o
In file included from ./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:34:0:
./fbpy/utils/test.h:10:1: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
 };
 ^
In file included from ./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:35:0:
./fbpy/utils/audio.h:36:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 int mainz();
 ^~~
In file included from ./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:36:0:
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.h:9:1: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
 };
 ^
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.h:17:1: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
 };
 ^
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.h:28:1: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
 };
 ^
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.h:43:1: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
 };
 ^
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.h:57:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 extern int keepcurrent();
 ^~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.h:59:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 extern int cleartmpbuffer();
 ^~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.h:60:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 extern int clearscreen();
 ^~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.h:64:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 extern int kernel();
 ^~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.h:70:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 extern int snow();
 ^~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.h:95:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 extern int getHeight();
 ^~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.h:96:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 extern int getWidth();
 ^~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.h:97:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 extern int styledredraw();
 ^~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:217:5: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 int keepcurrent()
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:319:5: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 int checkbounds()
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:355:5: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 int cleartmpbuffer()
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:361:5: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 int clearscreen()
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:392:5: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 int kernel()
     ^~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c: In function ‘plotalpha_’:
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:411:18: warning: unused variable ‘a’ [-Wunused-variable]
     float r,g,b, a;
                  ^
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c: At top level:
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:556:5: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 int snow()
     ^~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c: In function ‘snow’:
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:566:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘tvsnow’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     tvsnow();
     ^~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c: At top level:
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:587:5: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 int tvsnow()
     ^~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:691:5: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 int styledredraw()
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c: In function ‘styledredraw’:
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:726:17: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘transform’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                 transform(&xr, &yr);
                 ^~~~~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c: In function ‘rotate’:
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:801:12: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘R’ [-Wimplicit-int]
     static R[27]={4,8,7,5,0,1,2,3,6,
            ^
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c: In function ‘printxy’:
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:1186:18: warning: unused variable ‘backgrnd’ [-Wunused-variable]
     struct Color backgrnd;
                  ^~~~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c: In function ‘graticule’:
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:1221:15: warning: unused variable ‘dummycolor’ [-Wunused-variable]
  struct Color dummycolor;
               ^~~~~~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:1214:6: warning: unused variable ‘j’ [-Wunused-variable]
  int j;
      ^
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c: At top level:
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:1251:5: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 int getHeight()
     ^~~~~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:1256:5: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 int getWidth()
     ^~~~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:1454:5: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 int mandelbrot()
     ^~~~~~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c: In function ‘read_PNG’:
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:1511:43: error: ‘png_infopp_NULL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, png_infopp_NULL, png_infopp_NULL);
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:1511:43: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:1544:25: error: ‘int_p_NULL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
        &interlace_type, int_p_NULL, int_p_NULL);
                         ^~~~~~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c: In function ‘write_PNG’:
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:1724:22: warning: variable ‘color_type’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int bit_depth=0, color_type;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c: In function ‘setblurrad’:
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:226:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c: In function ‘tvsnow’:
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:598:2: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fread’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  fread(snow_buf, 1, surfsize, fp);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm presuming the context here is on a pi.

The error is *from* the C compiler, not about it.  If you examine `/usr/bin/gcc` you'll notice it's a symlink to `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`.  That's not a cross-compiler, that's the native compiler.

```
./fbpy/utils/fbutils.c:1511:43: error: ‘png_infopp_NULL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, png_infopp_NULL, png_infopp_NULL);
```

This is an error caused by an mysterious identifier, `png_infopp_NULL`.  This could be because of a header that's the wrong version, or some unusual path taken in the build process due to context.

You should have a look at `/usr/include/python2.7/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h`.  While I don't know anything about python modules, the rest of the half quoted warning, **"Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by..."** might be worth reading and may even lead to a solution.

Comment: A header missing completely, probably would have killed the compile with a different error, but I agree that the compile is failing because of this error emitted by the compiler due to the symbol being undefined. Another possibility is that it's a macro value that was supposed to be defined via a `-D` flag on the command line.  The warnings are not *directly* causing your problem, but they might also provide clues as to what's wrong, i.e. if you have the right headers / command line, all of those "prototype" warnings might also go away. Maybe.

Comment: Yeah, a missing header would throw a no-such-header error.